# How do I pull information from one wordpress backend into another?

Tags: php

I am not even sure this is possible, but here is what I have in my head. I have 3 installations of wordpress. They each run affiliate WP. I have a main management site where my affiliates log in and have access to a bunch of banks of training videos and documents and such to assist them in running the business. So, right now they have to log into each of the 3 shopping sites to view stats and such. Is it possible for me to pull these statistics from each of the shopping stores and create 3 seperate statistics pages within the 1 management site?

Comment: Woocommerce has an api that you can use to pull information.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to activate your WordPress as multi site and than add three sites.  Than you can import all your contents here in all these three sites.

Once get all in one WordPress you can manage it.

Otherwise you need api  to retrieve informations  from another WordPress  installations.